# Can we get custom SE schwag (for a higher price)?

Tags: discussion, shop

Is it possible to say, engrave my username, account info and possible even rep on a beer stein on the SE store? I'm sure many folks would pay more custom SE gear.

**Edit:**

Forgetting rep for a second, there's username and other profile info. Adding the current rep is just a convenient option I'd include for sake of completion.

Comment: your constantly changing rep?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff True, but say I'm at 10K or something?

Comment: or his fake inflated rep, duh

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff ~ YES! Can't you make that happen?

Comment: @Reb, would that be more expensive?

Comment: Imagine the money we'd make off Welbog!

Comment: @Rebecca I can build it, but who wants to program their wifi info into their beer stein just so they can watch their rep increase?

Comment: @AdamDavis - Can you really? I want to see this!

Comment: @Adam famous last words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest taking your stein or whatever other merchandise to a retail location such as http://www.thingsremembered.com/ who would specialize in doing that sort of thing for you.

Specialization, imagine that.

Besides all that, they exist in just about every large indoor shopping mall I've ever been in, in every major city. Granted, they may not be in *every* mall, but I can almost bet there's one close by. If not this company, one that does the same sort of thing.

You can even ship them stuff to get it engraved.

Comment: Or you can just give me your money and I will tell all your friends and coworkers that you are a weirdo. Just sayin'.